# Save prefabs to array

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

In my game, players shall be able to select units from a menu, which will later be used (placed) in various scenes.

For that, I want to save the unit prefabs in a static array through code.
I then want to access these prefabs, to display some of their variables declared in attached scripts (like name, power and a thumbnail texture) to display on the UI. Later, I want to instantiate them into the scenes.

So far, I fail to save these prefabs to the array.

My code:

```
//save to array
if (GUI.Button(Rect(h_center-30,v_center-30,50,50), "Ship A")){
    arr.Push (Resources.Load("Custom/Prefabs/Ship_Fighter") as GameObject);
}

//display on UI
GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), arr[i].name.ToString());
```

From the last line, I get this error:

```
<i>" 'name' is not a member of 'Object'. "</i>
```

So, where is my mistake? Did I forget something or declare it wrong, or is my approach here invalid to begin with (i.e, prefabs can't be saved/accessed this way; another type of list would fit this task better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the array without type. You can either declare the array as a list of `GameObject`s or cast the elements when you extract them.

Example of type casting:

```
GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), ((GameObject)arr[i]).name.ToString());    

// which is equivalent to
GameObject elem = (GameObject)arr[i];
GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), elem.name.ToString());
```

Example of using a generic list:

```
// Add this line at the top of your file for using Generic Lists
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Declare the list (you cannot add new elements to an array, so better use a List)
static List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();

// In your method, add elements to the list and access them by looping the array
foreach (GameObject elem in list) {
    GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), elem.name.ToString());
}

// ... or accessing by index
GameObject[] arr = list.ToArray;
GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), arr[0].name.ToString());
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick reply.
Secondly: I am using UnityJS, not c#. Hence, i used the JS Array, which has no declared type (i unsuccessfully looked for a way to define one).<br/>
So in order to get a defined type, i switched to a Generic List, which at least produces no errors in the editor. 
<br/>
However, when i run the scene, and press the button, the gameobject added to the list is empty, resulting in an error when the script tries to access its name. 
<br/>
So apparently, the way i save the prefab to the list isn't working.
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @user3802640 The `c#` tag confused me. Anyway the error is because you are trying to access the `name` property of a `Object` class (that doesn't have that property). Casting the element of the array to `GameObject` should solve your issue.

Comment: What i do now: 
**Inserting** `arr.Add (Resources.Load("Custom/Prefabs/Ship_Fighter.prefab") as GameObject);`
**Reading:** 
`GUI.Label (Rect (10, 10, 80, 20), (arr[i] as GameObject).name.ToString());`

Still, the gameobject created remains empty and i get this error: _"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"_

However, when i drag the prefab onto the empty gameobject in the inspector, the name is displayed as intended. I guess there's something wrong with the way I let unity read the prefab.

Comment: @user3802640 That's a different error, before you got a *compiler* error, now you get a *runtime* error, because the object that you are adding to the array is `null`. This usually means that the object is not being loaded correctly. Check that the Prefab is loaded by saving it into a variable first. Remember that you can also use step-by-step debugging in Unity to inspect the variable content.